# TensorFlow estimator number of classes does not change

Tags: python, tensorflow, machine-learning, deep-learning, mnist

I tried using tensorflow estimator for the MNIST dataset. For some reason it keep saying my `n_classes` is set to 1 even though it is at 10!

```
import tensorflow as tf
import numpy as np
from tensorflow.examples.tutorials.mnist import input_data
mnist = input_data.read_data_sets("MNIST_data/",one_hot=True)


feature_columns = [tf.feature_column.numeric_column("x", shape=[784])]

# Build 3 layer DNN with 10, 20, 10 units respectively.
classifier = tf.estimator.DNNClassifier(feature_columns=feature_columns,
                                        hidden_units=[500, 500, 500],
                                        n_classes=10,
                                        model_dir="/tmp/MT")
for i in range(100000):
    xdata, ydata = mnist.train.next_batch(500)
    train_input_fn = tf.estimator.inputs.numpy_input_fn(
        x={"x":xdata},
        y=ydata,
        num_epochs=None,
        shuffle=True)
    classifier.train(input_fn=train_input_fn, steps=2000)

# Define the test inputs
test_input_fn = tf.estimator.inputs.numpy_input_fn(
    x= {"x":mnist.test.images},
    y= mnist.test.labels,
    num_epochs=1,
    shuffle=False)

# Evaluate accuracy.
accuracy_score = classifier.evaluate(input_fn=test_input_fn)["accuracy"]

print("\nTest Accuracy: {0:f}\n".format(accuracy_score))
```

Error:

```
ValueError: Mismatched label shape. Classifier configured with n_classes=1.  Received 10. Suggested Fix: check your n_classes argument to the estimator and/or the shape of your label.

Process finished with exit code 1
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

That's a good question. [`tf.estimator.DNNClassifier`](https://www.tensorflow.org/api_docs/python/tf/estimator/DNNClassifier) is using [`tf.losses.sparse_softmax_cross_entropy`](https://www.tensorflow.org/api_docs/python/tf/losses/sparse_softmax_cross_entropy) loss, in other words it expects *ordinal* encoding, instead of *one-hot* (can't find it in the doc, only [the source code](https://github.com/tensorflow/tensorflow/blob/master/tensorflow/python/estimator/canned/head.py#L459)):

> `labels` must be a dense `Tensor` with shape matching `logits`, namely
>     `[D0, D1, ... DN, 1]`. If `label_vocabulary` given, `labels` must be a string
>     `Tensor` with values from the vocabulary. If `label_vocabulary` is not given,
>     `labels` must be an integer `Tensor` with values specifying the class index.

You should read the data with `one_hot=False` and also cast the labels to int32 to make it work:

```
y=ydata.astype(np.int32)
```

Comment: Thanks! It worked! :) 
But in the future I might need to use one hot encoding for other projects. Will DNNRegressor do the trick?

Comment: The regressor is doing regression task, so I'm afraid it won't help. I think one option is to use pure tensorflow, where you can define your own loss easily. See this example - https://github.com/aymericdamien/TensorFlow-Examples/blob/master/notebooks/2_BasicModels/logistic_regression.ipynb